# How to use KDE Storage Service Manager with Google Drive?

Tags: 16.04, kde, google-drive

I have installed KDE Storage Service Manager ([`storageservicemanager` package with version 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/storageservicemanager)) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with all updates.

And then tried to add Google account to it. Application asked for my Google account credentials and shown my Account size (Quota and Shared)

[image: Storage Service Manager - Google Drive]

but *Default Download Folder* location is empty. And the main GUI shows *Storage service not initialized* message, with *Network connection is up* in statusbar.

What should I do to make it working with Google Drive?

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS install the package `kio-gdrive` and then execute the following command in terminal `kioclient5 exec gdrive:/`
This will make the google drive available as a Network Drive in the Network section of the File manager (Dolphin, as you mentioned you are using KDE). Thus to use your Google Drive, just go to Network section and choose the google drive Network folder.

Comment: `kio-gdrive` [is not available](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=kio-gdrive) for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (*xenial*). Do you have other solutions for 16.04 LTS?

Comment: Try rclone. That can be used with any (almost) type of storage service. All you have to do is to edit rclone.config or you can use Gnome online accounts package. That works similar to kio-gdrive